# a representation of permutation groups

Tags: group-theory

The smallest degree of faithful permutation representations of $S_k$ for $k\geq 6$
have degrees $k$ (natural action), $2k$ (imprimitive action on cosets of $A_{k−1} )$, and
$k(k − 1)/2$ (action on unordered pairs). (This is a part of an answer in mathoverflow.net by Derek holt)

My question is: what is the centralizer of third representation in $S_{\binom{k}{2}}$ ? and the above list is all faithful permutation representation of $S_k$?

Comment: The stabilizer of an unordered pair in $S_k$ is self-normalizing for $k>4$, so the centralizer of the image in $S_{\binom{k}{2}}$ (which is actually primitive)  has order $1$. It has order $2$ when $k=4$.

Comment: Professor Holt@ thanks. and the above list is all faithful permutation representation of S_k?

Comment: No, those are just the representations of smallest degrees. There is a huge number of faith representations of larger degree.